# Calculating percentage change using R with two independent variables

Tags: r, percentage

I could definitely do this using a pen and calculator but thought it would make sense to do in R. I've used Rmisc to produce a table of the means, sd, se and ci for my data.

> summarySE(data=Chloro,"ChlorophyllSq", groupvars = c("Treatment", "Time"), conf.interval = 0.95)

I have three independent variables (treatment (4 factors), time (5 factors) and depth (2 factors)

Is there a way to find percentage change in the chlorophyll mean between different time points in different treatments? I want to find the difference between chlorophyll between time point 1 (pre treatment) and 5 (last time point) in all different treatments (1,2,3,4).

I'm then potentially interested in breaking it down to include depth in percentage change too, but would have to alter summary to include depth:

> summarySE(data=Chloro,"ChlorophyllSq", groupvars = c("Treatment", "Depth", "Time"), conf.interval = 0.95)

Comment: You can use aggregate function in R. `aggregate(Chloro[,c("Treatment", "ChlorophyllSq)],  by = list(Chloro$Treatment),
                FUN = mean)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate in R to get the average of treatment group.
`aggregate(Chloro[,c("Treatment", "ChlorophyllSq")], by = list(Chloro$Treatment), FUN = mean)`

To calculate percentage change you can define a function to calculate the change and apply it

```
pct <- function(x) {x/lag(x)}    
Chloro%>% group_by(Treatment) %>% mutate_each(funs(pct), c(ChlorophyllSq))
```

You can use `dplyr` to get the first and last row

`Chloro%>% group_by(Treatment)%>%  filter(1:n() %in% range(1:n()))`